# Do 'true' and 'false' have their usual meaning in preprocessor conditionals?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, preprocessor

Given a C++11 compiler, which `#error` is the correct one it should end up with?

```
// no #includes!
#define SOMEMACRO true
#if SOMEMACRO
  #error "it was true"
#else
  #error "it was false"
#endif
```

[Godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xnhheW)

Obviously I'm using `#error` just as a test. I know `true` and `false` are defined in the language proper, but this is preprocessor context. In C99 it seems not to be recognised by the preprocessor.

I'm asking because it seems that all compilers I tried see it as 'true', while a static code analysis tool insists that `true` isn't defined, implicitly false and ends up in "it was false".

Comment: C++: yes they are keywords; C: no they aren't (`stdbool.h`).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In all ISO C++ standards, both `true` and `false` are keyword constants, just like `nullptr` in C++11. So `#if SOMEMACRO` = `#if true` and the preprocessor will go to the truthy branch.

In C, however, neither `true` nor `false` is ever a keyword. They're macros defined to `1` and `0` respectively, as of C99 *and* with `#include <stdbool.h>`. This *does* mean that however, if you don't include `stdbool.h`, the compiler should complain about unrecognized identifiers for `true`, `false` etc. After including the header, `#if SOMEMACRO` is now `#if 1`, which is truthy in C.

For preprocessing, this quote from [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/conditional#Conditional_evaluation) is meaningful:

> Any identifier, which is not literal, non defined using `#define` directive, evaluates to *0*.

So in your (probably C-oriented) static analysis tool, it sees `true` as a non-`#define`-defined identifier, and therefore evaluates `true` to zero. You're not going to observe this behavior if you use a C++ analysis tool.

In that case, you probably shouldn't have missed the `#include <stdbool.h>` in the first place, though.

Comment: For reference, `true` and `false` are [specifically singled out](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/cpp.cond#4) to not be replaced when other identifiers are replaced. `nullptr` is a literal, but it doesn't get this treatment, which you can see with a condition such as `#if nullptr + 2 == 2` that would fail to compile if `nullptr` were not replaced with `0`.

Comment: @chris, I read it but there is no explanation of the why. Do you have an explanation?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, I can only speculate, but `true` and `false` being replaced by `1` and `0` would cause the literals to lose their boolean type by the time the preprocessor is finished and the actual language takes over.

Comment: @chris, but in C, if `stdbool.h` is included, then true and false _are_ #defned and have no boolean meaning. Only in C++ they have, but then they shouldn't be defined in stdbool. Is the same preprocessor used for C and C++?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, As far as I'm aware, the preprocessor is identical apart from very minor differences like this one (e.g., I've had Boost.PP work in C). The C preprocessor existed before `_Bool` so it makes sense that there's no special case there (even today where the definitions are 1 and 0), but it seems there was little disadvantage to maintaining type information in C++ in this particular case when it had `bool` and such-typed literals from the beginning. And that is correct, in C++, stdbool.h provides no `#define`s for `bool`, `true`, and `false` since they're part of the language proper.

Answer (score 8):

According to [cpp.cond]/4 in [the C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf):

> Prior to evaluation, macro invocations in the list of preprocessing tokens that will become the controlling constant expression are replaced (except for those macro names modified by the `defined` unary operator), just as in normal text. […] After all replacements due to macro expansion and the `defined` unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers and keywords, **except for `true` and `false`**, are replaced with the pp-number `0`, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting tokens comprise the controlling constant expression which is **evaluated according to the rules of [expr.const]** using arithmetic that has at least the ranges specified in [support.limits]. […] Each **subexpression with type `bool`** is subjected to integral promotion before processing continues.

Emphasis mine; from the bolded passages it follows that `bool`-typed expressions are meant to be supported in preprocessor conditions just like in the language proper, including `bool` literals `true` and `false`. The [expr.const] section defining constant expressions is referred to from other sections that use it in non-preprocessing context, from which it follows that the evaluation rules are the same in the preprocessor and the language proper.

I’d assume similar language appears in all further revisions of the C++ standard, and probably in earlier ones too. In C, on the other hand, `true` and `false` are not keywords, but macros defined in `stdbool.h`, so the preprocessor treats them just like any other token.

The usual practice is to use `1` and `0` for logical values in preprocessor expressions for maximum portability, and preferably to avoid directly referring to them entirely.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers already pointed out correctly, `true` and `false` should work there with C++ compilers.

OP here: it was indeed a configuration problem of the SCA tool. In Helix, the option `-preproccppkeywords`, which says "When enabled, the C++ alternative tokens are treated as keywords." was responsible for this. When switching on, it behaves as expected. `true` and `false` are recognized during preprocessing.