# Why doesn't #define SOMETHING TRUE work for #if?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

The following code prints `main.cpp:20:19: note: #pragma message: serial disabled`. I had expected that "enabled" would be printed. What is wrong with the code?

```
int main()
{
#define SERIAL_ENABLED TRUE

#if SERIAL_ENABLED
  #pragma message "serial enabled"
#else
  #pragma message "serial disabled"
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `TRUE` has not been defined, so its value is 0.

Comment: You probably want `#ifdef SERIAL_ENABLED` or you miss *some header* defining `TRUE`

Comment: Contrary to popular believe, `true` is not guaranteed to work either. Use `1` instead of `TRUE`.

Answer (score 5):

TRUE is not defined. Use true.

Comment: I'm not sure `true` is a preprocessor token in the same way `1` is. Its meaning may only be available in later translation stages. This may very well have the same issue.

Comment: Seems to work: https://godbolt.org/z/bhxW8qq4c

Comment: @JaMiT On what compiler? MSVC accepts `#if true` aswell as `#if 1`

Comment: @JaMiT -- "Seems to work" is not the same as "is required to work".

Comment: @JaMiT You are correct in C. C++ allows keyword constants as tokens. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66098267/3832484

Comment: The C++ preprocessor is required to treat `true` and `false` specially by *not* expanding them to `0` if they are undefined as macros in an `#if`. So in `#if true` the constant expression to be evaluated is indeed just `true` and not `0` and since that `true` evaluates nonzero the branch must be taken. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/conditional

Comment: Well, there's a core issue that certainly indicates it *should* work [cwg1436](https://wg21.link/cwg1436). Given the problem in the report is that the specification is *too* lax, and the fix attempts to keep boolean literals a valid thing, I guess this is really fine.